# Binding 127.0.0.1 on Azure IIS Site in ServiceDefinition.csdef

Tags: azure, azure-worker-roles

How?

I only saw `hostHeader` in `ServiceDefinition.csdef` `Bindings` Section.
Where do I put IP?

Comment: What are you trying to accomplish? Yuu sould NOT IMHO be trying to bind your Azure services to a specific IP.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is not possible to add a binding to 127.0.0.1 in your ServiceDefinition.csdef file.  Instead, you'll have to add a binding node to the appropriate site section of D:\Windows\System32\inetsrv\config\applicationHost.config.

You could do this in two ways:

1. Use the [Microsoft.Web.Administration](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/carlosag/archive/2006/04/17/microsoftwebadministration.aspx) assembly to alter the applicationHost.config.  For example you could add the following code to the OnStart method of your RoleEntryPoint derived class:

   ```
   Microsoft.Web.Administration.Site site = server.Sites.FirstOrDefault(s => s.Name.Equals("NameOfWebsite"));

   Microsoft.Web.Administration.Binding binding = site.Bindings.FirstOrDefault(b => b.Protocol == "http");
   site.Bindings.Remove(binding);
   site.Bindings.Add("*:80:", "http");
   server.CommitChanges();
   ```
2. Use D:\Windows\System32\inetsrv\appcmd.exe to alter applicationHost.config in a startup task (see [this link](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc731692%28v=WS.10%29.aspx)).

Out of curiosity, why do you want to add the 127.0.0.1 binding to your web role?